# Do you actually time travel using the Time Matrix?

Tags: time-travel, animorphs

Something I didn't quite understand when reading "The Andalite Chronicles" was the Time Matrix.  It was hyped up to be this ancient time traveling device, but whenever it was first used, it looked like they did travel through time, but it there were some details that were off, like the fast food worker with no eyes, the girls mother knowing about aliens, so on and so on. The only other time we see it used in that story, they just transport to Earth, not the past.

My question is, did the Time matrix actually travel through time, or was it some unique dimension created for everyone?

Comment: Psst.. Megamorphs 3 also involves the Time Matrix

Comment: Yeah. Read Megamorphs 3 and you will learn a lot about the Time Matrix. @Izkata

Comment: @Fiksdal Yeeaah, that's what I said - why did you @ me?

Comment: @Izkata It was for OP. Don't know why I pinged you, lol :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Time Matrix was capable of true time travel, but if a past that didn't actually exist was requested (such as the past containing the mixed wants of the protagonists and Yeerks, which you cited), [a unique dimension was create to fit those desires.](http://animorphs.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Matrix) Source: Seerowpedia.